# How can I find which item in which RecyclerView was tapped?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I currently have a layout that has 4 horizontal `RecyclerViews` in succession. They all display how they are supposed to. However now I want to be able to click on a specific item in a `RecyclerView` and have it bring up more information. I have the click working with a single `RecyclerView` by overriding the `onItemClick` method. The only problem is I have 4 and I can't tell which `RecyclerView` is being clicked.

This is how I currently do it with one `RecyclerView`.

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {        
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DetailedInfo.class);
    intent.putExtra(DETAILED_INFO, customAdapter.getVideo(position));
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

I have all of the `RecyclerViews` in a list so I can grab a specific one like this:

```
((VideoAdapter) recyclerViewList.get(1).getAdapter()).getVideo(position));
```

I just don't know how to find the one that was actually clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could do this inside adapter. pass your activity as context to your adapter.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, DetailedInfo.class);
            intent.putExtra(DETAILED_INFO, getVideo(position));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```